# Trouble using tag property of UITextView to add a UITextView to a UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview

I have a grouped table where each row is it's own section.  I am trying to have two of the rows have UITextViews as a subView of the UITableViewCell's contentView.  This is my cellForRowAtIndexPath method (the pertinent part):

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:LeftDetailCellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:LeftDetailCellIdentifier];
}
if (section == kFirstSection) {// some code }

else if (section == kNameSection) {
    cell.textLabel.text = @"name";

    UITextView *nameTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 12, kTextViewWidth, kTextViewHeight)];
    nameTextView.text = self.address.name;

    nameTextView.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0];
    nameTextView.tag = kNameTextViewTag;
    nameTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    nameTextView.delegate = self;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:nameTextView];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
else if (section == kNotesSection) {
    cell.textLabel.text = @"notes";

    UITextView *notesTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 12, kTextViewWidth, kTextViewHeight)];
    notesTextView.text = self.address.notes;

    notesTextView.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0];
    notesTextView.tag = kNotesTextViewTag;
    notesTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    notesTextView.delegate = self;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:notesTextView];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
```

I know my sections are correct because in my UI, I see name and notes accordingly.  However, my UITextViews end up both having orangeColor.  (I don't want the color, but I am trying to troubleshoot why I'm getting the wrong values in my textView delegate methods).

In my constants file, I have the tags declared as:

```
const NSInteger kNameTextViewTag = 10;
const NSInteger kNotesTextViewTag = 20;
```

For some reason, my tableViewCell's end up having the wrong textView in them.  Is there a reason for this?  I'm assuming it has something to do with the dequeuReusableCellWithIdentifier method, but not sure.  Thanks!

**EDITED**
From Martin's comment, I tried this, but still doesn't work:

```
 static NSString *NameTextViewCellIdentifier = @"NameTextViewCellIdentifier";
    static NSString *NotesTextViewCellIdentifier = @"NotesTextViewCellIdentifier";


else if (section == kNameSection) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NameTextViewCellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:LeftDetailCellIdentifier];
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = @"name";

        UITextView *nameTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 12, kTextViewWidth, kTextViewHeight)];
        nameTextView.text = self.address.name;

        nameTextView.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0];
        nameTextView.tag = kNameTextViewTag;
        nameTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        nameTextView.delegate = self;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:nameTextView];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        return cell;
    }
    else if (section == kNotesSection) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NotesTextViewCellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:LeftDetailCellIdentifier];
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = @"notes";

        UITextView *notesTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 12, kTextViewWidth, kTextViewHeight)];
        notesTextView.text = self.address.notes;

        notesTextView.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0];
        notesTextView.tag = kNotesTextViewTag;
        notesTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        notesTextView.delegate = self;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:notesTextView];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        return cell;
    }
```

I have the UITextViewDelegate in my parent class of this class since I have another class that also uses code to resize the UITextView on demand.

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    // Calculate the size of the text to reload the height for that table row
    NSString *tempString = textView.text;
    NSString *trimmedString = [tempString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    NSLog(@"tag: %i ", textView.tag);
    if (textView.tag = kNameTextViewTag) {
        self.address.name = trimmedString;
    }
    else {
        self.address.notes = trimmedString;
    }

    [self setTextViewSize:textView]; // set proper text view size

    UIView *contentView = textView.superview;
    // (1) the padding above and below the UITextView should each be 6px, so UITextView's
    // height + 12 should equal the height of the UITableViewCell
    // (2) if they are not equal, then update the height of the UITableViewCell
    if ((textView.frame.size.height + 12.0f) != contentView.frame.size.height) {
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];

        [contentView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                         0,
                                         contentView.frame.size.width,
                                         (textView.frame.size.height+12.0f))];
    }
}
```

So my tags are still incorrect.  When this delegate method gets called by the name textView, the correct tag index gets logged.  However when I update the notes textview, it logs the correct textView for one key entry, and then starts logging the name textView again.  Not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use different reuse identifiers for each cell type, otherwise it can happen that a cell that you constructed for the "notes section" is later reused for the "name section" or vice versa.

Comment: I tried that just now.  I added the code I tried above.  It still does not work.  My backgroundcolors look correct, however when I start editing the appropriate textView in the tableViewCell, I log the UITextView tag, and for the 2nd cell (notes), it first logs the correct tag, then it starts logging the 1st cell (name).  Not sure why still.

Answer (score 0):

After creating a test project where it worked, I relooked at my code to see where it was breaking.  In my textViewDidChange method, I made the noob error of = instead of ==.  Sorry for the trouble!

```
if (textView.tag = kNameTextViewTag) {
        self.address.name = trimmedString;
    }
    else {
        self.address.notes = trimmedString;
    }
```

Comment: Fine that it works now, but this seems to be a different problem than your first question. If using different reuse identifiers was necessary to solve your *original question* then you should "accept" my answer. Otherwise you should "accept" your own answer to get this question removed from the "unanswered questions" list.